# Unclear about how git push affects remote branch

Tags: git, git-merge

I have a newbie git question. Lets say my repository picture starts off like this:

```
A <-- B <-- MASTER       |       A <-- B <-- O/M
```

I make some changes to local master and in the meanwhile someone updates the remote master too. So I have:

```
A <-- B <-- C <-- D <-- MASTER  |  A <-- B <-- E <-- F <-- O/M
```

Now I get cranky and do a 'git pull'. From my understanding I should now see:

```
                 O/M
                 |
                 V
      ---- E <-- F ------
      |                 |
      V                 ^
A <-- B <-- C <-- D <-- G <-- MASTER  |  A <-- B <-- E <-- F <-- O/M
```

Am I right so far? Now I decide to git push to remote master. I am a little unsure as to what kind of graph I should see on the remote. Is it:

```
A <-- B <-- E <-- F <-- G <-- O/M
```

that doesn't look right. or is it:

```
A <-- B <-- C <-- D <-- G <-- O/M
```

that one doesn't convince me either.

I have read git push only works if the remote can do a fast-forward merge with the stuff you are trying to push. I can't reconcile that the statment with what the final graph on the remote should look like.

Comment: When you push, the other repo ends up with exactly the history you pushed or it rejects it for not being a descendant of what it already has.  Your `G` descends from its `F`, so it'll take it.  If what you're working on is part of some work that's being prepared for publication to a trunk or otherwise major branch, consider doing `pull --rebase` and pushing the result of that, that'll keep the history of the production branch easier to eyeball in the end.

Comment: The `git push` causes the remote to have exactly the same diagram as you have titled "From my understanding I should now see:" (left-hand diagram only), except "O/M" now points to "G" rather than "F".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Out of order:

> I have read git push only works if the remote can do a fast-forward merge with the stuff you are trying to push.

That's the default constraint for branch updates (updates to references of the form `refs/heads/whatever`).  Remotes can establish other rules, but that's probably the one in force.

It's also worth noting that "fast-forward" is really a property of a *label move*, rather than the merge itself.  The `git merge` command chooses to do a fast-forward when possible and not told otherwise, and that is indeed called a "fast-forward merge" in various places (although the `git merge` man page says "when the merge resolves as a fast-forward", which is a subtle distinction).

> I ... do a 'git pull'

The pull script is shorthand for:

1. fetch, then
2. merge or rebase (as directed, default = merge).

Let's assume "merge".  Rather than the graph you drew, though, let me write it this way:

```
        C - D        <-- master@{1}
      /       \
A - B           G    <-- master
      \       /
        E - F        <-- origin/master
```

where `G` is the merge commit, `G^` is `D`, `G^2` is `F`, and so on.  (This can also be drawn:

```
A - B - C - D - G
      \       /
        E - F
```

but that makes it harder to put the `master@{1}` label on it.)

One key to understanding this is that the labels, which I've pushed over to the right a bit, are purely in *your* repository, and they are just labels.  (By "just labels" I mean they are not permanent the way repository objects—commits, and the stuff that goes with each commit—are.  They can be "peeled off", like labels written on sticky-notes, and pasted on other different objects later, or even thrown away.)

Now if you do a `git push`, your git contacts their git and the two talk a bit about what they have.  Yours says: "I'd like to give you commit `G` and make your `refs/heads/master` point there."

Theirs then says: "I don't know anything about `G`, tell me more!"  Yours describes `G` as pointing back to both `D` and `F`; theirs knows `F` but not `D`, so yours tells them about `D` pointing back to `C`, and then about `C` pointing back to `B`, and now the two are all caught up.<sup>1</sup>

At this point, theirs can look at the proposal to update their `refs/heads/master` to point to `G` and determine whether moving their `master` from `F` to `G` would be a fast-forward.  It would, so they will accept it, and make their `master` branch point to commit `G`.

Your git does not actually tell them about your `master` branch at all, in this process!  It just says "I'd like you to point your `master` to commit `G`".  They then merely look to see if that's a fast-forward for *them*.

---

<sup>1</sup>Of course, there's a bit more to it than this: the "conversation", such as it is, is really about git objects, and when yours sends over the commits it also has to send any required tree and blob objects.  The label update happens afterward as well.  But overall, this is the effect.

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand this alleged "conversation" much better now :-)